# Matching a csv file and output in Shiny

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I would like Shiny (RStudio) to load a `csv` file and have it report a result. Very similar to the code I attached, but instead of a `textInput` I would like the input to be a `csv` file, which will be a column with a title and multiple rows with characters.

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Thank you very much for the support.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(id=as.character(c("A", "B", "C")),stock=as.double(c(210.57,94.42,412.31)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput(inputId = "stock", "Stock", placeholder = "i.e. 210.57"),
  actionButton(inputId = "click", "Click"),
  tableOutput(outputId = "table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  result = eventReactive(input$click, {
    df %>% filter(stock %in% input$stock) %>% 
      distinct(id, stock) %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      slice(first(which(stock >= input$stock)))
  })
  
  output$table = renderTable({
    result()
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I haven't tried anything yet, because I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [fileInput()](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html)

Comment: Waldi, thanks. I need a little more help, though, to achieve what I think.